# Bootstrap Grid picture attached

Tags: html, css

I have some problem dealing with bootstrap Grid. See image below

[image: Problem],

let me tell you what I want to do but I couldn't, I want it to be like below picture. And row 1 takes 70% of the page and the other row takes 30%.

[image: Demo2]

and columns fill the row "same height", see "Demo2.jpg" to understand me =(

note: I'm still learning, sorry for inconvenience. 
my code:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">

                            <div class="panel-heading ">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 1 </h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body" >
                                <div id="container"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="panel border-top-info border-bottom-info" >
                            <div class="panel-heading ">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 2 </h6>
                            </div>


                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 3 </h6>
                            </div>


                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 4 </h6>
                            </div>


                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 5 </h6>
                            </div>


                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">PANEL 6 </h6>
                            </div>


                        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">Top and bottom borders</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel with top and bottom <code>info</code> borders
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">Top and bottom borders</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel with top and bottom <code>info</code> borders
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">Top and bottom borders</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel with top and bottom <code>info</code> borders
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">Top and bottom borders</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel with top and bottom <code>info</code> borders
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-flat border-top-info border-bottom-info">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h6 class="panel-title">Top and bottom borders</h6>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                Panel with top and bottom <code>info</code> borders
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably use flex instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the col-md- directives for vertical sizes, which doesn't work. The col- part stands for column, so all that manipulates is the width of an element. I'm not aware of any directives that allow you to do the same with heights...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to have a container div.

It's either container or container-fluid class.